# icontains unable to search certain words from a field that uses richtext field - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I made a search function in my project where a user can enter a query and a number of fields will be searched before sending a response with the data filtered. As usual I am using icontains in the views for making the queries in my model. I copied certain words directly from a field that uses ckeditor to the searchbar to see if it works. What I have noticed is it is unable to match certain that are in bold form. [image: Image of that field]

In the image for example if I search the words **arbitration agreement** no data is returned but as you can see the words exists in the field. This is happeing with all the bold words.

Please help me to solve the problem as I am unable to understand as to why this is happeing. Below is the view that deals with the search functionality. Using ckeditor for the field.

**views.py**

```
def search_citation(request):
    
    q = request.data.get('q')
    
    print(f'{q}')
    
    if q is None:
        q = ""
    
    if len(q) > 78 or len(q) < 1:
        
        return Response({"message":'not appropriate'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    try:
      
      judge_name = Civil.objects.filter(judge_name__icontains = q)
      
      case_no =  Civil.objects.filter(case_no__icontains = q)
      
      party_name =  Civil.objects.filter(party_name__icontains = q)
      
      advocate_petitioner = Civil.objects.filter(advocate_petitioner__icontains = q)
      
      advocate_respondent = Civil.objects.filter(advocate_respondent__icontains = q)
      
      judgements = Civil.objects.filter(judgements__icontains = q)
      
      institution_name = Civil.objects.filter(institution_name__icontains = q)
      
      title = Civil.objects.filter(title__icontains = q)
      
      sub_law_type = Civil.objects.filter(sub_law_type__icontains = q)
      
      law_category =  Civil.objects.filter(law_category__icontains = q)
      
      q_final = judge_name | case_no | party_name | advocate_petitioner | advocate_respondent | title | sub_law_type | law_category | judgements | institution_name
      
      q_serial = Initial_Detail_Serial(q_final, many = True)
      
      return Response(q_serial.data, status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
      
    except Exception as e:
        
        print(e)
        
        return Response({"error":str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: By any chance is it the case that instead of "arbitration agreement" being formatted as bold as a single run you've formatted them _separately_? For example if the output format is markdown then the output is `**arbitration** **agreement**`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am not sure I actually copied it. But I tried to pull out this in JSON format and realised 
that it has a whte space (&npsp;) in between. So may be that is why it is not able to match